# Wikipedia JSON parser in python

Tags: python, json

i want to print extract of Wikipedia pages
but for each search the page no is changed so how to print extract with wildcard for page no.

i tried following code

```
import urllib2
import json

response = urllib2.urlopen('https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Stack%20Overflow')
data = json.load(response)   
print data["query"]["pages"][0][extract]
```

but it gives error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/GM/Desktop/pytest/pytest.py", line 6, in <module>
    print data["query"]["pages"][0]["extract"]
KeyError: 0
```

please help

Comment: Well, key `0` does not exist in `data["query"]["pages"]`, which is a dictionary. Error is self-explainatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
print data["query"]["pages"].values()[0]["extract"]
```

This creates a list of all of the values in the "pages" dictionary. In your example, there is only one value, so `[0]` gets it.

If there is more than one value, one of them will be returned. It is unpredictable which one.

Answer (score 1):

If you `print data["query"]["pages"]`, you will see that it is a dict, not a list.  Try `print data["query"]["pages"]["21721040"]["extract"]`

Comment: but if i want some random page then each time i have to enter page no. is there any wildcard for page no??

Comment: You can iterate over the keys of a dict: `for pageid, page in data["query"]["pages"].items(): print page["extract"]`

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this your best bet is to print the parent structure. In this case, you can do this with:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(data["query"]["pages"])
```

If you do that you'll see that the structure is a `dict` and not a `list` as you appear to be expecting. It looks like the key is the numeric page ID in string form, and the value is a dictionary containing `extract` which has the extract you're looking for.

I'm guessing that the search you're doing is actually searching titles of Wikipedia pages and so multiple matches can be returned. If you know the page ID you're looking for you can look it up, but I suspect it's more likely you'll have to iterate through the items:

```
for extract in (i["extract"] for i in data["query"]["pages"].values()):
    print extract
```